# Is MacBook Pro 2016 with Touch Bar Compatible with Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: macbook, compatibility, 17.04

I was wondering if anyone tried to install the new Ubuntu release on a MBP with TouchBar?

Any updates regarding the drivers?

Comment: I know this is old, but here's a guide on how to install Linux on a MBP with touchbar. https://dev.to/cmiranda/linux-on-macbook-pro-2016-1onb

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Situation isn't as bad as last year when it came out but it's still pretty bad. Not just for Ubuntu but for whole Linux

List of Devices and their respective state as of *now*

[image: Screeshot]

Even booting as it is isn't possible, you need to change kernel parameters for that

if you want to tinker with it you can try to install it but if you want to use it on daily basis I will recommend you not to do so

[GitHub  State of Linux on the MacBook Pro 2016](https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux)

Comment: In the need for a stable development environment. I already have the MBP so I can't change that, and my current solution is a VirtualBox which works but can be frustrating here and there. What you posted is relevant for Ubuntu 16, 17 or both? And of course, thanks for the reply.